# Order of Jetty rewrite rules

Tags: url-rewriting, jetty

I'm working with some simple Jetty rewrite rules

```xml
<Configure id="FileServer" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
    <Get id="oldhandler" name="handler"/>
    <Set name="handler">
        <New id="Rewrite" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler">
            <Set name="handler"><Ref id="oldhandler"/></Set>

            <Call name="addRule">
                <Arg>
                  <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteRegexRule">
                    <Set name="regex">/fake-uri/(.*)</Set>
                    <Set name="replacement">/real-uri/$1</Set>
                  </New>
                </Arg>
            </Call>

            <Call name="addRule">
                <Arg>
                    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.HeaderPatternRule">
                        <Set name="pattern">/real-uri/*</Set>
                        <Set name="name">Cache-Control</Set>
                        <Set name="value">no-cache,no-store</Set>
                    </New>
                </Arg>
            </Call>

        </New>
    </Set>
</Configure>
```

If I request `/fake-uri/index.html` in the browser, the response contains what would be served by `/real-uri/index.html` *and* applies the *Cache-Control* headers. However, if I reorder the rules so the header rule is above the regex rule, the *Cache-Control* headers are absent for requests to `/fake-uri/index.html`.

Seems like order is important here, but I'm trying to workout what's happening. According to [the doc](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/7.6.13.v20130916/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/rewrite/handler/RewriteHandler.html)

> HeaderPatternRule - adds/modifies the HTTP headers in response

I'm unsure what the default is, but I've tried

```
<Set name="rewriteRequestURI">true</Set>
```

on the handler.

It doesn't seem to change anything, but I'd think if the **request** URI were rewritten, it wouldn't matter where the URI rewrite rule appeared in relation to a header rewrite which applies to **output** headers. Thing is even with *rewriteRequestURI* set to *true*, the header rule has to come second for the desired effect. So why is order important when I've set *rewriteRequestURI*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The processing order is top-down and the rule engine continues to process rules until a rule terminates the processing.

Even though the HeaderPatternRule updates the Response it matches the URL on the Request. This is why the Cache-Control only is added if the order is such that the URL first is re-written to match the second rule.

The other part of your question about the following parameter:

```
<Set name="rewriteRequestURI">true</Set>
```

Doesn't really apply to what you are trying to do. The rewriteRequestURI parameter tells the rewrite engine to also update the `HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI()` like you said, but this doesn't affect the rule engine, but only how the Servlet applications are affected by the rewrites.

All that matters in the rule engine is ordering and if any rule terminates the processing with the statement:

```
<Set name="terminating">true</Set>
```

That would stop the rule engine.

One confusing note is if you use Redirect rules instead of the Rewrite rules. That would trigger the rule engine to be executed again on the Redirect. That way you can re-process rules from the beginning again (and create infinite loops)

Comment: To be fair, a Redirect rule causes a new request, so thats the core reason the rules run again.

Comment: Right, only to highlight that a rewrite rule doesn't, which could be confusing since they look very similar in the config.